# Using variable in Batch FOR loop

Tags: batch-file

I have the following statement in windows batch.

```
set machinename=%1
@FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env --shell cmd default') DO @%i
```

How to replace default by my variable "machinename" ?

Comment: Are you just looking for how to use variables in batch?

Comment: That code will never work in a batch file.

Comment: After you've fixed the code in response to @Squashman's comment, replace `default` with either `%1` or `%machinename%`

Comment: Open a command prompt window and run `for /?`. This outputs the help for command __FOR__ with first sentence in fourth paragraph: *To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
of %variable.* Next run `call /?` and it is explained in output help how arguments can be referenced in a batch file. Then run `set /?` and the output help explains the usage of environment variables. And if you need a list of commands, run in command prompt window `help`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i IN ('docker-machine env --shell cmd "%~1"') DO %%~i
```

There is no need to have the `machineName` variable, as `machineName` points to `%1`. The `~` denotes to remove surrounding quotes, and add back extra quotes, just as a precaution.

Also, `%i` should be changed to `%%i`. `%i` is for command-line, and `%%i` is for a batch file.